# Sort a view with a sql sentence in drupal 6

Tags: sql, sorting, drupal, view

I would know what I have to do to sort a view with a SQL sentence. I have a website where I have a lot of items, and a table in the DB where I record every click done in each item.

The items shown in the webside are made with a view so that I would like to sort this view with a SQL sentence that return the number of clics of each item sorted DESC. Does Someone know what I should do to get it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the number of clicks as a property of your items, this way you can easily sort them with Views.

In your item content type you just create a "number of clicks" field that gets updated every time an item gets a click...